# Temporarily close 5" hole in plexiglass

Tags: windows, vent

I have a portable AC unit venting through a 5" hole in a plexiglass window. I replaced the glass window with a plexiglass one to do this since the windows that open are casement-style. The AC unit is not needed in the winter so I'd like to move the AC unit into the closet to free up the space. What is an elegant way to plug the hole (it is near the entrance so aesthetics is important) so that it is only removable from one side?

Update: The glass is not easily removable - at least not easy enough to justify swapping panels twice a year. Indoor temperatures reaching triple digits lowered our aesthetics standards for the summer... but I'm avoiding crude solutions like taping on a can lid.

Comment: Is the plexiglass easily removable? If so, replace it with a plexiglass sheet without a hole in it.

Comment: Aesthetics are not important in summer then.

Comment: Can you reach the outside of the window? Two 15 cm circles of wood with a coach bolt going through, fastened with a wing nut, could suffice. Colour the wood as needed. Add a groove with a rubber sealing strip if the wind howls in around the edge.

Comment: Depends on what you view as "aesthetic."  Similar to AMorton's comment, I'd put a 7" by 2" plexi strip on the outside, held in place w/ a flat-head bolt that goes thru a 5.5" diameter plexi disc on the inside with an o-ring to seal and a wingnut to secure the assembly. easy to install and remove from inside the house.